# Vvidget_GG.framework and Vvidget_GS.framework part of OS X default install?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I downloaded some example code to draw a line graph in Cocoa. The example is not running because Vvidget_GG.framework and Vvidget_GS.framework do not exist. I searched in my /System/Library/Frameworks and /Library/Frameworks folders to add them to my project, but they are not there on my system.

Do these frameworks exist by default on OS X?

Answer (score 0):

They are definitely not part of any Apple SDK — apparently, [they’re sold by Vvidget](http://www.vvidget.org/developer/index.html).